# Where to look during takbeer in salah?

Tags: salat

When we start our salah and say takbeer (Allah u Akbar), at that time we should look down or we should look straight towards kibla?

Answer (score 0):

In prayer, from the start till the end, one should be looking at the place where the forehead is placed during sajdah.This is the opinion of the Islamic scholars. **Qibla** is just for the sake of direction, its imagination during the prayer is not necessary. However one should be cognizant of Allah; as if either he is seeing Allah or Allah is seeing him (called {H} **Ihsan**).

Comment: When writing e.g. "this is the opinion of the Islamic scholars", I encourage you to link to reliable references giving examples of Islamic scholars stating that opinion.  (Anyone on the internet can write "this is the opinion of the Islamic scholars" about anything.)